# Better improvement requests options for Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-examples

The current options for Improvement requests are only the following:

[image]

All of them come out as somewhat negative. I simply wanted to let the author know of some improvements that I felt that could improve his already very helpful documentation.

It's certainly not **rude or abusive**.

It's definitely far from **unclear**.

It's clearly *not* **not an example**.

It's surely anything but **very low quality**

And it's the last thing that would be **in need of moderator intervention**

Could we perhaps have more *friendly* improvement requests? I feel that I'm being forced to belittle my fellow SO denizen. In my case, I felt that a simple comment could sent the message through but comments are disabled for documentation-examples.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what options you'd like to see or different phrasing for the existing ones? We're about to start work on a discussion feature that should hopefully alleviate some of this sort of problems as well.

Comment: @Adam - How about a custom option? Or perhaps incomplete? Or perhaps [citation needed]? Or more code? Or more explanation? Maybe any of those could be considered... food for thought :)

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks! I like "incomplete". I'm still considering splitting out flagging (e.g. "in need of moderator intervention") from requesting improvement. I'll bring that up again on our next team call to either start forming a plan for it or give it up for the time being. If we do the split, a custom option would be suitable - and would still feed into the Discussion feature plans.

Comment: The current options available seems more appropriate for flagging bad posts. It would be great is if we could do side-comments / line-comments like in google docs or medium.com, but this of course brings up a lot of other considerations.